# Can you make the background in Google Docs in different colors?

Tags: google-docs

I want to change the color of my Google doc background to different colors, but I can't figure out how! Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a document in Google Docs. The document can be either an existing document or a new document.
2. Select *File* -> *Page setup...* to open the Page setup window.

   [image]
3. Under the **Page color** heading select a page color from the dropdown menu.
4. Click the *Set as default* button.
5. Click the *OK* button.